# Getting Average Precision as - 1 or 0 in Faster RCNN pytorch implementation on pytorch

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection, pytorch-lightning, faster-rcnn

I'm new to machine learning and I have followed the tutorial to fine-tune the head of a faster-rcnn for a custom dataset (top-down drone imagery) to detect trees within images.

After a small amount of tuning (5 epochs) just to test this works, I'm getting the following assessment using the pytorch **evaluate** function, showing Average Precision as either 0 or -1 (which I thought would be impossible):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1JwU.png)

The model seems to be making predictions. But I would have thought even if the predictions were terrible, the AP wouldn't give these values? Any ideas of what could be going wrong here?

I've being editting the following tutorial to suit my needs:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/yerramvarun/fine-tuning-faster-rcnn-using-pytorch

Thanks